# Django 0.96 to Django 1.2 on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms, python-2.7

In configuration.py:

```
FOOTER_HTML = ( 'Powered by <a href="http://code.google.com/appengine">GAE </a> ' )
```

In base.html :

```
<div id="footer">
   {% block footer %}
   {{ configuration.FOOTER_HTML }}
   {% endblock %}
</div>
```

This is rendering as expected in Django 0.96 / Python 2.5.2 but not rendering as expected in
Django 1.2 / Python 2.7.2

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: FOOTER_HTML should be rendered as part of the html page. In the Django 1.2/ Python 2.7.2 environment FOOTER_HTML value is rendered as text.

Comment: So, 0.96 would insert the value verbatim, but 1.2 escapes the special HTML characters so you see what looks like HTML source?

Comment: Yes Matt. HTML tags are escaped in the new environment.

Comment: try {{ configuration.FOOTER_HTML|safe }}

Comment: Thanks, matt and dragonx . this worked

Comment: In both cases they are rendered as expected.. according to the Django docs at least..  :) Maybe not as desired.. but either case @dragonx you should write that as an answer... or this question should be deleted..

Comment: If you're going to upgrade Django versions, you should at least read the release notes of the versions you're upgrading through. Autoescaping is clearly explained in the 1.0 release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the django templates documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

To quickly fix this, use

```
{{ configuration.FOOTER_HTML|safe }}
```

However, there's other ways to do this, as described in the template docs.

For future reference, if you probably should explain what isn't working.  Instead of simply saying something is "not rendering as expected", you should show what you expect, and what you're getting.  You should also explain what fixes you've tried that didn't work.

Otherwise, you're expecting people to read your mind.